# Edit with IDLE option is not available after installing Python 2.7 alongside Python 3.5. What should be done?

Tags: python, python-idle

My IDLE option in the right click menu has disappeared.

I think it's because I use Python 3.5.2, but I installed Python 2.7.12 without uninstalling Python 3.5.2. Later I uninstalled Python 2.7.12 and from then on the `.py` files are opening in either Chrome but I cannot get it to open with IDLE. And the usual logo for Python scripts has disappeared. Instead now it has the logo in the picture. What can I do? I uninstalled Python 3.5 after the problem and reinstalled it. Yet the problem persists.

[image: New logo of Python files/scripts]

Comment: right click on the file > open with > choose default program > browse > **your python installation** > Lib > idlelib > idle.bat

Comment: If this is on Windows, installing multiple versions of Python is no problem, and the install for 2.7.12 should have had no effect on the install of 3.5 unless you selected 2.7.12 as the default install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative approach would be to `modify your Python installation`. I would advice against reinstalling Python because you stand to lose your installed modules and scripts. But if you don't mind starting over again, `reinstalling Python` will fix this.

To modify your Python installation:

1. Open the `Control Panel`.

   [image: Control Panel Screenshot]
2. `Uninstall` Python Launcher.
3. Click on Python 3.6 (or the version you
   have.)
4. Choose Modify.
5. On the *Optional Features* page, make sure the
   `.py launcher checkbox` is checked.
6. Proceed and wait for the setup to finish.

After it's done, you can either restart your computer or
    sign out then sign in.

Now when you right click on your `.py files`, Edit With IDLE will show up in the context menu. Keep in mind that your `.py files` should *Open With* Python Launcher.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**
Right click on any `.py` file and click `Open With` and click `choose default Program` or `Choose another app`.

From the list that appears after if you see `python.exe` choose that otherwise click `Choose another program` or `Browse` option. Might that option appears after clicking `More App` in Windows 10.

Next browse to python insallation directory and select `python.exe`

**Option 2:**
Run `regedit` and goto key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.py` and change the default to `Python.File`.

After that logout & login. Context menu will appear again.

Comment: Tried both. In fact the logo appeared after I tried the **Option 1** .Tried **Option 2**; did not work.

Comment: Ok try Option 2 & after that try again Option 1.

Comment: @AdnanUmer Thanks a lot. The only solution worked for me (Y)

Answer (score 1):

At time of saving python code...will display two extensions `.py` and `.pyw`.
Save file using `.pyw` extension, i.e. instead of `dropcols.py` save it as `dropcols.pyw`will solve your problem. This worked for me.